# How can I pull specific information from a log file linux red hat

Tags: linux

I have a 500mb log file that I need to pull the backup info from.
I need the date then the two lines to follow. Its also fine if the other days appear.

```
Fri Feb  8 00:00:02 2013
14:58:01  Level 0 Archive started on rootdbs, physdbs, logidbs, dbspace01
15:32:56  Archive on rootdbs, physdbs, logidbs, dbspace01 Completed.
```

Thanks

Comment: It would probably help if you post some surrounding lines, so that posters can validate their regex

Comment: What's your end goal here?  Are you trying to set up monitoring on whether your backups completed successfully?  In any case, you really need to put full timestamps on every line in a log file.  Relying on the context of surrounding lines is fraught with danger.

Answer (score 5):

Try `grep -A2 "Fri Feb  8 00:00" /your/log/file`